# In atom how to auto complete function arguments?

Tags: python, atom-editor

i'm new to atom, I think I installed them all, `autocomplete`, `autocomplete-python` `autocomplete-plus` (see image below).  But it only completes function names, I don't see it's auto completing **function arguments**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an older thread, but I thought I'd respond for anyone who stumbles onto the post. I recently had this issue with Atom and found the `kite` package to be a great option for the argument functionality you reference above (and much more). See below:

- Installation :
  [image: Installation]
- Kite & Pandas: read_csv()
  [image: Kite & Pandas: read_csv()]