# Atom autocomplete-python: Arguments? More documentation? Prefixes?

Tags: python, autocomplete, atom-editor

I'm trying to set up the Atom's autocomplete-python package on my Mac (10.11.6) and have three related questions...

**1)** As I type a python keyword, arguments ARE displayed, but how do I make them print to my document?  For example, when I type "DATABAS", autocomplete offers this option:

> c DATABASES { 'default': { 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backend...

Hitting the enter key to select this option only prints the command "DATABASES" to my file.  What keystrokes are needed to also print the arguments?  The readme's suggestion of open parenthesis only prints that character, even though my US keyboard setup  seems to be sending the correct Unicode U+0028 with this key.

- The package's "Autocomplete Function Parameters" is set to "all"
- autocomplete-plus is installed, and seems to be functioning: Typing "open", enter key and "(" adds the arguments for that command.  Adding "*.none" to that package's "File Blacklist" setting seemed to have no effect on my autocomplete-python question.
- Jas asked [what may be the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48468686/in-atom-how-to-auto-complete-function-arguments) but there are no answers, so I'm trying again with different wording and more research results.
- walles posted [an issue in 2015](https://github.com/autocomplete-python/autocomplete-python/issues/111), which prompted a package change.  But that new Atom command "Autocomplete Python: Complete Arguments" doesn't seem to do anything just after I select the "DATABASES" option, nor after I manually select the entire word "DATABASES".

What am I missing here?

**2)** Is there more documentation for autocomplete-python that I haven't found yet?

**3)** autocomplete-python offers prefix letters before the offered options.  (The "c" above, apparently meaning "Command".)  Has a legend been published for all possible prefixes?  That would help me learn more about python.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To be more specific on #3:  Besides the package readme, is there another documentation source that I should be looking at?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your unexpected behavior. On atom 1.27.2 with autocomplete-python 1.10.5 and the file
```
def foo(a, b=1): return a, b
def bar(a, b): return a,b
```
complete arguments of `foo(` fills in `a)`, while `bar(` completes to `a, b)`.  Complete arguments doesn't work without the cursor within parens.  What versions do you have, and can you give an example python file?